# Find images for complex mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Hi I am working on the following problem.
For the mapping $w=\frac{2}{z}$ find the images where $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$:

(a) of the circles $x^2+y^2-2x=0$ and $(x-1)^2+y^2=4$

(b) of the lines $x=1$ and $x=0$

(c) of the strip $0<\text{Re }z<1$

I found the following

(a) u=1 and $(u+\frac{2}{3})^2+v^2=\frac{16}{9}$

(b) $(u-1)^2+v^2=1$ and $u=0$

(c) This is the region on the positive $u$ axis outside the circle of radius 1 with center $(1,0)$

It would be a great help if you could help me whether my solution is correct or not? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parts a) and b) are correct.

for part c) it should be the region outside the circle centre $(1,0)$ and radius $1$ and to the right of the imaginary axis

Comment: Sorry my statement wasn't clear, I meant the right side of imaginary axis by positive u axis. Thanks a lot.